# calculate the distribution and density of the variable $Y=X^2$

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution

$$ \mbox{Let X have the normal distribution: } N(0,\sigma^{2}) \to E(X)=0, Var(X)=\sigma^{2}. \mbox{ Let's define a new variable: }Y=X^2. \mbox{  Calculate the distribution and density of Y} $$
Is that solution correct?
$$f_{X}(x)= {{1}\over{(2\pi)^{1/2} \sigma}}e^{{-x^2}\over{2\sigma^2}}$$ $$F_{X}(x)= {\phi({{x}\over{\sigma}})} $$ $$ F_{Y}(y)=P(Y<y)=P(X^2<y)=P(-{y}^{1/2} < X < {y}^{1/2})=F_{X}({y}^{1/2})-F_{X}(-{y}^{1/2})=\phi({{y}^{1/2}\over\sigma})-\phi({{-y}^{1/2}\over\sigma})= 2\phi({{y}^{1/2}\over{\sigma}}) $$ But I still don't know how to calculate the density of $Y$.

Comment: to obtain the density differentiate the distribution!

Answer (score 3):

Let's start form

$$\frac{X}{\sigma}\sim N(0;1)$$

It is well known, and anyway easy to prove that

$$W=\Bigg(\frac{X}{\sigma}\Bigg)^2\sim \chi_{(1)}^2=Gamma(1/2;1/2)$$

Thus

$$Y=\sigma^2\cdot W=Gamma(1/2;1/(2\sigma^2))$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate last step? How did $\sigma^2$ fit in distribution?

Answer (score 2):

> Could you please elaborate last step? How did $\sigma^2$ fit in distribution?

Let's have

$$X\sim Gamma(n;\theta)$$

(I mean $\theta$ is the rate parameter)

$$f_X(x)=\frac{\theta^n}{\Gamma(n)}x^{n-1}e^{-\theta x}$$

Let's set

$$y=\sigma^2 x$$

$$x=\frac{y}{\sigma^2}$$

$$x'=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}$$

thus

$$f_Y(y)=f_X[g^{-1}(y)]\Bigg|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)\Bigg|=\frac{\theta^n}{\Gamma(n)}\Bigg(\frac{y}{\sigma^2}\Bigg)^{n-1}e^{-\frac{\theta}{\sigma^2} y}\cdot \frac{1}{\sigma^2}$$

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{\Big(\frac{\theta}{\sigma^2}\Big)^n}{\Gamma(n)}y^{n-1}e^{-\frac{\theta}{\sigma^2}y}$$

that is

$$Y\sim Gamma(n;\theta/\sigma^2)$$